# Some Part of the Outlets are Not Showing While Running on Different OS Versions in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, xib

I Have Developed an Application. In that one i Added a GMSMapView and also Two Buttons at the Bottom. If i run this Application on iOS Simulator Version 7.0 all the outlets on the XiB are Visible. But If i run this Application on iOS Simulator Version 6.1 one of the Button is not Visible. Can any one please tell what is the Reason why it is hiding one button if the Height of the Device is Same.

[image: iOS 7]

[image: iOS 6]

Comment: Can you show some screen shots?

Comment: are you using autolayout or any run time update on those controls?

Comment: No. I am Not Using Autolayout.

Comment: Is the button placed in the bottom? then it may go down in iOS6. Use xib preview in XCode 5.

Comment: use ios 6/7 delta to Y -20

Answer (score 0):

You can use delta value that will effect the layout for the ios 6 not to the ios7

[image]

Comment: I Was Unable to See the Above Screen. Where it is Located.

Comment: Click on the button. go to size inspector at the bottom of the frame there is option.jaha pe frame change karte he na iske bilkul niche hi he

Comment: Sorry There is no such option. At the Bottom of Frame change there is Constraints.

Comment: You said that you are not using auto layout

Comment: Sorry i found it. and also changed deltaY to -20 the other button is not visible.

Comment: try to change with larger value check its effecting or not

Answer (score 0):

if you are set view as ios 7 in interface buinder you need to decrease you y position show image below

[image]

[image]

-64 delta y because you use navigationbar at top so it's size 44 and +20 for status bar

Comment: set for all uiview like UIButton,UILabel